# Are there any books with history short/summarised stories?

Tags: ancient-history, book, mongol-empire

I was recently reading Atrocities by Matthew white, which has stories about the 100 greatest atrocities in world history. It is the first history book I have managed to complete. I prefer to read a short account of the incident and then go in an internet rabbithole later, instead of picking up an exhaustive history book and failing to go past the first chapter. Please recommend other such books! (preferably something about east asian history, although i am open to other topics)

Comment: Please review [help] and associated discussion on meta.  Like many  other stack exchange sites, subjective recommendations are [bad shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)  Unless there are authoritative references, it simply isn't possible to select an authoritative answer from all the opinions provided.   There are many sites on the internet where this question would be in scope and would get good answers. History's scope and community culture has determined that it is not within our scope.

Comment: _Plutarch's lives_ comes to mind as does  _1066 and all that_

Comment: thanks a lot! Sorry if I voilated some question etiquette, I am new here

Comment: No apology needed.  It is not an illogical question to ask - but such questions tend to generate more discussion/debate than answers. We regretfully redirect them to other, more appropriate sites.  Good luck.

Comment: @MCW, and "12 caesars" by Suetonis. I read it as a kid. Because of that I am more familiar with Roman history until the 1st century AD than what followed: me the kid got the silly idea that the book covers all that's interesting about the Empire and I didn't follow up  with other books until a decade later.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the Chinese histories. The point is that while Western history books combine multiple stories to form one sweeping narrative, the [Chinese history style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Records_of_the_Grand_Historian) is to "break it up into smaller, overlapping units dealing with famous leaders, individuals, and major topics of significance".

The original books are probably impossible to read, but there are surely modernized versions/translations around.

Comment: could you give a few recommendations?